# SlidingPaneLayout items in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, slidingpanelayout

I'm populating a `RecyclerView` with several `SlidingPaneLayout` items, as to achieve a 'swipe to delete' functionality (basically, dragging an item to the right reveals a DELETE button)

Problem:
When I drag an item to the right, it seems like the `RecyclerView` also intercepts my touches, and if my drag is somewhat diagonal (or not too horizontal) - the `RecyclerView` starts scrolling and the `SlidingPaneLayout` cancels the closing/opening of the pane

I've tried adding a touch listener to each `SlidingPaneLayout` that prevents the RecyclerView from intercepting the touches once `ACTION_DOWN` is performed on the `SlidingPaneLayout`, but that's not good as it blocks scrolling right away

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

Prevent the RecyclerView from intercepting touch events given the following condition:

10% < sliding pane offset < 90%

i.e

```
ViewParent parent = ...; // Should be the RecyclerView
parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(slideOffset > 0.1 && slideOffset < 0.9)
```